Telescoping Closed Form Induction
Sorry for no formatting, i don't know how it works here.
The question is:
Using induction, for n in the natural numbers, demonstrate sum of i^2 from i=1 to n is equal to (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6.
I got to the point of telescoping the values to:
a_{n} - a_{1} = 3 + 5 + ... + (2n-1)
a_{n} = 3 + 5 + ... + 2n
And had a few other side parts like:
a_{n} - a_{n-1} = n^2
a_{n} - a_{n-1} = 2n-1
But I got nowhere else with it.

[edit] the question to use mathjax for formatting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
